# Admin sale order create edit text box

Tags: magento2, admin, orders

Im trying to move the "City" box up and I cant find the template for it for the admin
can someone tell me where I can find it and change it [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link,
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/frontend/reorder-input-fields-shipping-billing-step-magento-2/

Make changes in sort order as per the requirement for the fields.